# Admob ads now showing from two weeks

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

My reward ads match rate was about 90% but after 26 November match rate dramatically decrease down to 30%. Is it global problem or specific to my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be happening to quite a few people (me including)
There is a whole thread on it on the google product forums with no official response so far

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-help-forum/8oc3pebOrFw;context-place=forum/google-admob-help-forum