# Admob ads disappear after apk publish

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android application that use Admob to display ads. When I tested the application on my mobile phone before publishing it to the play store every thing was perfect and ads appear normally.

After publishing the app to the play store and download the live version the application doesn't show any ads.

How can I fix the problem ?

Comment: How did you set up your production ads?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I followed the documentation on the admob site to add the ads

Answer (score 0):

This is not your problem. It's a global problem but Google don't say anything about it. 
Check these:

[Admob: BannerAd don't show on clients phones.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621126/admob-bannerad-dont-show-on-clients-phones)

[Admob ads now showing from two weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611921/admob-ads-now-showing-from-two-weeks/53617977#53617977)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-help-forum/8oc3pebOrFw;context-place=forum/google-admob-help-forum